# Creating a new Database using mysql on command line

Tags: mysql, database, magento, command-line

```
mysql> create database magento;  
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'magento'
```

How can I fix this and create a new database?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials that you are using to create the database do not have CREATE privileges granted.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create for CREATE rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new database for testing purposes, perhaps look into XAMPP - it allows (through the use of PHPMyAdmin) the creation of databases and tables within those databases. Otherwise, you might need to contact the MySQL administrator to grant you privileges for making new databases.

Answer (score -1):

This is a permission error. The way to fix it is to grant the user (which you are logged in as) permissions to create a database.

Something along the lines of

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

You will need to be logged in as a user who has permissions to grant permissions to other users in order to do this though. (`root` user would be good to use if you have access)

Comment: GRANT ALL is an overkill

Comment: You are correct. I am being sloppy. Hopefully Medina Ali trys to understand the command, not just blindly copies and pastes it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this- will be great if you can mention the steps i need to take for getting the username and password